# Error in torch package on virtual env pycharm

Tags: python-3.x, virtualenv, torch

Im working on virtual env on pycharm (python 3.6) and i installes the torch package through pycharm without any error.

while I'm trying to debug my code i get this error:

> from torch._C import *
>
> ImportError: libshm.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

If i not work on virtualenv the torch package works without no problem.

thanks